# In Android Oreo 8.0, how do accessibility options interfere with enhanced data encryption?

Tags: settings, encryption, accessibility

In Android Oreo 8.0 many accessibility options such as Select to Speak, TalkBack, and Switch Access show a similar message:

> If you turn on TalkBack your device won't use your screen lock to enhance data encryption.

Does this mean that the screen lock and/or data encryption will not work properly when choosing to turn on the chosen accessibility option, or does this mean that the way the screen lock enhances data encryption will no longer be active. How does the device use screen lock to enhance data encryption?

[Homescreen > Settings > Accessibility > TalkBack > On => message in question]

Comment: I guess the notice is misleading, it simply means that talkback by-pass your screen lock. On the other hand, there are two basic encryption option: 1) full encryption, phone does not boot 2) data encryption, phone boots without unlock (required for talkback working)

Comment: I tried it: one outcome was that the phone no longer required a password for starting up. This was against a certain device policy, so I had to turn it off again (and find out how to require the password again).